# Win8 and Cilk++

Tags: windows-8, cilk-plus

I was willing to create an app for IntelAppUp store.I came across Cilk++.I was wondering how to use this C++ library in C # application while building a form based application?Any insight will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Cilk++ is unsupported.  It has been replaced by Intel® Cilk<sup>™</sup> Plus, which has been implemented by the Intel Composer XE C++ compiler (Composer XE 2011 or later), as well as in the "cilkplus" branch of GCC.

You'll need to be careful mixing Cilk Plus and C# forms. Cilk Plus provides an easy-to-use fork/join parallelism mechanism.  Inside the parallel region, there's no way to predict which thread a piece of code will run on.  You'll need to be aware of the limitations of C# forms and threaded applications.  A good primer on the issues here is the article "Safe, Simple Multithreading in Windows Forms" available at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms951089.aspx .  You might also look at the QuickDemo example which shipped with Composer XE for Windows.  Admittedly, QuickDemo is an MFC, not WinForms, based application, but it demonstrates many of the same issues.

```
- Barry Tannenbaum
  Intel Cilk Plus Runtime Development
```